# Can I use AlUpdate instead of lUpdate for ipmi update on supermicro servers?

Tags: update, ipmi, supermicro, bmc

I have several different SuperMicro servers and I want to create an internal repository with firmwares and create a package with updating utility. In the ipmi firmware archives that I downloaded from supermicro web site, they include update utility for linux. For older motherboards (for example, X9DRW-7TPF) it is called lUpdate, but for more modern motherboards (for example, X10SLM-F), it is called AlUpdate and have higher version. Seems like internally that utility has the same name and developed by the same vendor. When you launch that utility, you get a header message, that looks like this:

```
***************************************************************************** 
* ATEN Technology, Inc.                                                     * 
***************************************************************************** 
* FUNCTION   :  IPMI FIRMWARE UPDATE UTILITY                                * 
* VERSION    :  2.07                                                        * 
* BUILD DATE :  Jul 13 2016                                                 *
```

Are they interchangeble? Could I use a more recent version of utility for more older motherboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not work. You have to use utility of older version (that was included in archive with firmware).

But there is a better solution: you can use supermicro update utility (sum) for updating. It can update ipmi  firmware on both generations of servers, so you do not need to use several binaries for utility of different versions. Also, sum is able to update bios on many motherboards. It is more convenient to do with linux than preparing a dos usb stick. Also, it is possible to flash it remotely, but that requires a licence key.
You can download it [here](https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/supermicro-update-manager).

Comment: I have recently discovered that one of that utility (lupdate or alupdate, do not remember) can flash bmc remotely too. Just see its help message. I will edit an aswer when I will remember for sure, but now I just keep it in comment.